# Replacing Ansible with Terraform scripts

Tags: ansible, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I was recently given a project to essentially rewrite all the ansible code the team is using to create infrastructure in terraform. I always thought ansible was just for configuring servers but it seems that its also able to create cloud resources much like terraform. The trouble is that it seems to be able to do tasks which I dont think are possible in terraform and I'm not sure how to approach it.

For example one of the scripts creates a vnet in Azure which is something I can easily translate into terraform. However its also doing things like calculating CIDR blocks.
Specifically it looks like its getting a list of all possible VNETS and then getting a list of my Azure subscriptions and the associated existing VNETS. Then its filtering those out of the initial list
Can terraform do something similar or would I need to invoke some kind of script or call ansible from Terraform?

```
- name: Calulate cidr for new vnet 
  block:

- name: Calulate number of available vnets in vnet_base
  set_fact:
    gen_vnet_count: "{{ vnet_base | ipsubnet(subnet_size | basename) }}"

- name: Generate all available subnets
  set_fact: 
    gen_vnet_list: "{{ gen_vnet_list  | default([]) + [vnet_base | ipsubnet(subnet_size | basename, item)] }}"
  loop: "{{ range(0, gen_vnet_count | int) | list }}"

- name: List all available subscriptions
  command: >
    az account list --query "[*].id"
  register: subscription_list
  retries: 2
  delay: 30
  until: subscription_list is succeeded

- name: Get existing ccs vnet's from all subscriptions
  azure_rm_virtualnetwork_info:
    subscription_id: "{{ item }}"
    client_id: "{{ vault_azure_client_id }}"
    tenant: "{{ vault_azure_tenant_id }}"
    secret: "{{ vault_azure_client_secret }}"
    tags:
      - "deploy:ccsvnet"
  loop: "{{ subscription_list.stdout }}"
  register: existing_vnets
  retries: 2
  delay: 30
  until: existing_vnets is succeeded 

- name: Filter out existing vnet CIDR ranges
  set_fact:
    existing_vnet_list: "{{ existing_vnets | json_query('results[*].virtualnetworks[].address_prefixes[0]') }}"
    
- name: Set selected_cidr
  set_fact:
    selected_cidr: "{{ (gen_vnet_list | difference(existing_vnet_list)) | first }}"
```

Comment: Right, while Ansible is a configuration management tool, where you delcare a final state, Terraform is a provisioning tool.

Comment: I haven't picked your code apart to figure out to what extent a direct equivalent is possible, but Terraform does have several functions for calculating CIDR blocks (cidrhost, cidrnetmask, cidrsubnet, cidrsubnets). I personally use them to take a single integer ID for an environment, and from that calculate all subnet CIDR's, so hopefully you can do similar. https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/cidrhost.html

Comment: ah okay, I didnt know that. thanks for the tip

Comment: Your question is way too broad to be answered, I suggest you to learn a bit terraform and then see how you would achieve it there, then come with specific questions.

Comment: I dont think my question is that broad given that I have provided an example. The ansible code is calculating a CIDR block for a VPC/VNET. Its doing that by getting al list of all the Azure subscriptions and filtering out the existing ones from the list . I have terraform experience and certification and from my knowledge of terraform it cant perform tasks like this. Therefore I am wondering if anyone else has had a similar challenge and how they solved it. I know terraform can call ansible using local exec but this is something different entirely

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your comment @clockworknet.

You can use Terraform to calculate CIDR blocks.

Below are the available functions to calculate CIDR blocks :

**cidrhost** : cidrhost calculates a full host IP address for a given host number within a given IP network address prefix

**cidrnetmask** : cidrnetmask converts an IPv4 address prefix given in CIDR notation into a subnet mask address

**cidrsubnet** : cidrsubnet calculates a subnet address within given IP network address prefix

**cidrsubnets** : cidrsubnets calculates a sequence of consecutive IP address ranges within a particular CIDR prefix

I  tested with **cidrsubnet** function in my environment for calculation of CIDR blocks for  subnet

[image]

**Reference** : [cidrhost - Functions - Configuration Language - Terraform by HashiCorp](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/cidrhost.html)